# MongoDB full text search on string array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, full-text-search

So I'm using Node.js with MongoDB for my web application. I'm having some trouble creating a text index for my schema and searching for text within an array. I've looked at the mongo docs but haven't found anything related to this specifically.

My current implementation searches successfully on regular String values, but querying for text matching in [String]'s don't return anything.

Here's my REST call:

`...console.log("Query string: " + str);
  var qry = {
    "$text": {
       "$search": str
    }
  };
  model.find(qry, function (err, results) {...`

And when I create my schema:

`var blah = new Schema({
    foo : String,
    bar : [String],`

...

`blah.index({
      foo: 'text',
      bar: 'text'
    });`

Any query won't return the results that match in `bar`. A query string for something within `foo` works fine.

Comment: Please post the statement you've used to create your text index. This is relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Double check that you've created the correct indexes on the correct collections and the queries are being issued to the correct collections. Indexing an array works for me:

```
> db.test.drop()
> db.test.insert({ "_id" : 0, "a" : "dogs are good" })
> db.test.insert({ "_id" : 1, "a" : "I like dogs", "b" : ["where's my dog?", "here, have a cat"] })
> db.test.insert({ "_id" : 2, "b" : ["she borrowed my dog", "my frogs are croaking"] })
> db.test.ensureIndex({ "a" : "text", "b" : "text" })
> db.test.find({ "$text" : { "$search" : "dogs" } }, { "_id" : 1 })
{ "_id" : 0 }
{ "_id" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I finally figured it out! Turns out, grunt serve doesn't update indexes in the database. I had created a text index for "foo" only and that didn't update when I added "bar" to the index. I had to run - in mongo shell:

`db.dropDatabase()`

The next time I ran it, the database was recreated and the proper indexes were set. If anyone else runs across this issue, try running `db.getIndexes()`.